# QGIS points filter

Tags: qgis, point, qgis-2, filter

I'd like to use the points filter tool in the QGIS processing toolbox to remove errant gps points from data i'm looking at. I've had limited success playing with it and I was hoping someone who is more familiar with the tool might be able to fill in the blanks.

Specifically

```
Attribute - Does this have any effect on the points filter?
Radius - Buffer to see how close points are to you
Minimum Number of Points - Min number of points in buffer created above
Maximum Number of Points - Max number of points in buffer created above
Quadrants - No clue, any ideas?
```

Filter Criterion Options: (What is minima and maxima, and what percentile are they talking about?)

```
0 — [0] keep maxima (with tolerance)
1 — [1] keep minima (with tolerance)
2 — [2] remove maxima (with tolerance)
3 — [3] remove minima (with tolerance)
4 — [4] remove below percentile 
5 — [5] remove above percentile
```

Answer (score 1):

alright, captain clever (i.e. me) has just realised that there is a slider bar on the right where you can scroll down to select percentile and tolerance. I believe the words are 'doh'